# Can't see the owning side from an inverse side JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this piece of code:

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
}
```

and:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")

public class Post extends BaseEntity{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
Person person;
@Column(name = "text", nullable = true)
private String text;
}
```

The issue is that when I connect to my Hibernate database I can see the Person Id in the Post entity, but can't see the Post id in the Person entity. There is no person_post table neither. How can I see the posts that belong to the person? I want to list the posts from the person using thymeleaf but something like this doesn't work:

```
  <tr th:each="post : ${person.posts}">
            <td th:text="${post.text}">nothing in here</td>
 </tr>
```

Error says that thymeleaf can't see the posts in Person. Is this how it is supposed to work? How can I list the posts from person?
Thanks in advance, Tomasz

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a 1:N relationshop, that means that in the Post table there is the person_id foreign key, but no intermediate table person_post. However person.posts should give you the result you are looking for - can you add the logic how you add the Person / Post and the controller method of the template?

It's recommended to user LAZY fetching, by the way: https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/

Comment: Hi, I have a runner class
@Component
public class Runner implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>

Where I put data:
        Post firstPost = new Post();
        firstPost.setText("this is first post");

        Post secondPost = new Post();
        secondPost.setText("this is second post");
        Person person = new Person();
        firstPost.setPerson(person);
        secondPost.setPerson(person);
        person.getPosts().add(firstPost);
        person.getPosts().add(secondPost);

Comment: What is interesting, when in this Runner class when I run person.getPosts().size() it returns 2, which is correct. However in database it can't retrieve posts from person.

Comment: From the code you mention, there is no repository.save(entity) call? You may have a look at https://bootify.io (create your entities with rest controllers) to see how this saving part could work.

Comment: All this creation of the new instantions of classes are in the method getPersons() that is being invoked in:
@Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        personRepository.saveAll(getPersons());
    }
and the PersonRepository looks like this:
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}

Comment: Are there Post's created in the database?

Comment: Yes, all the posts are in the database, with all the info: post's ids, post's text, and the foreign key to the person entity.

Comment: That looks all fine to me - maybe it's an understanding issue? if you want to find "Post of Person X" in the database, you need to query the Post table where the foreign key matches the Person id. There is no separate list.

Comment: So when I use thymleaf to list all the field of Person, let's say I will have name, surname and the aforementioned posts, I have to do it like this (simplified):
person.name
person.surname
post.person_id(of person above)

Comment: Your thymleaf snippet from your original post looks fine. I'm sorry, all what you say looks good :-)

Comment: Well that's my luck. Thank you for all your time :)